# Given a root of $x\tan x-1 = 0$, how to approximate the next one?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, optimization, numerical-methods, approximation

Let $f(x) = x\tan x-1$. 
Let's consider when $f(x)=0$.

In the neighbourhood of every $k\pi$, where k is an integer, there should be a solution for $f(x)=0$.

Assuming  $x_0$ approximately satisfies $f(x)$, is it correct that the next solution can be approximated to be at  $x_0 + \pi - g(x)$ ?

If so, how can I find $g(x)$ to approximate the position of the next root to an arbitrary precision?

Comment: What is wrong with using [Newton's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) and just adjusting the start points ?

Comment: Isn't it over-complicated to apply Newton's method over and over, when the roots are coming in a predictable pattern? The distance between roots is increasing, and the rate at which that distance is increasing is decreasing. It appears that the distance between roots converges to $2\pi$. Could this somehow be exploited to come up with a formula for the distance to the next root, or the position of the next root?

Comment: It seems like this is mostly a duplicate of your previous question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3490480/a-formula-for-the-distance-between-maxima-of-x-cosx), just applying some reductions pointed out in the comments; it's not so great to have both these questions, since it could easily happen that one could get answered, then the other could receive an almost identical answer from someone who was not aware of the prior solution.

Comment: @MiloBrandt You're right, I've gone ahead and deleted the previous question.

Comment: @Kos Despite your concerns I will post an answer to your question using Newton's method. It is somewhat ugly but it works well

Comment: Thanks, looking forward to it!

Comment: But the comment about Newton's method could be a good start, that by picking $x_0+\pi$ as an initial guess, then an approximation could be 

$$x_1 = x_0 + \pi - \frac{f(x_0+\pi)}{f'(x_0+\pi)} = x_0 +\pi+g(x_0)$$

where $g(x) =  - \dfrac{f(x+\pi)}{f'(x+\pi)}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for the zero's of function
$$f(x) = x\tan( x)-1$$
 which are close to multiples of $\pi$.

I think that it is better to consider instead the problem of the zero's of function
$$g(x) = x\sin( x)-\cos(x)$$

What can easily be done is to expand $g(x)$ as a Taylor series around $x=k \pi$ and to proceed later to a series resversion.

This would give
$$\color{blue}{x_{(k)}=q+\frac{1}{q}-\frac{4}{3 q^3}+\frac{53}{15 q^5}-\frac{1226}{105
   q^7}+\frac{13597}{315 q^9}-\frac{1531127}{8960 q^{11}}+\frac{84665251}{120960
   q^{13}}+O\left(\frac{1}{q^{15}}\right)}$$ where $\color{blue}{q=k \pi}$.

Using the above truncated series (which could easily be extended), below are reproduced some results
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 k & \text{approximation} & \text{exact solution} \\
 1 & 3.4256889465952269449 &   3.4256184594817281465 \\
 2 & 6.4372981816942647058 &   6.4372981791719471204 \\
 3 & 9.5293344053667719230 &   9.5293344053619636030 \\
 4 & 12.645287223856678278 &   12.645287223856643104 \\
 5 & 15.771284874815881554 &   15.771284874815882047 \\
 6 & 18.902409956860023945 &   18.902409956860024151 \\
 7 & 22.036496727938565037 &   22.036496727938565083 \\
 8 & 25.172446326646664703 &   25.172446326646664714 \\
 9 & 28.309642854452012361 &   28.309642854452012364 \\
 10 & 31.447714637546233552 &   31.447714637546233553 \\
 11 & 34.586424215288923664 &   34.586424215288923664
\end{array}
\right)$$

Answer (score 2):

A preliminary remark: The equation $f(x)=0$ is equivalent to $\tan(x)=\frac1x$. Now, $\tan$ is $\pi$-periodic and continuous, so for large $x$, the solutions will be arbitrarily close to the solutions of $\tan(x)=0$ which is just $x=\pi n$ for $n\in\mathbb Z$. This is why (almost) all your solutions are close to multiples of $\pi$.

---

Using Newton's method we can give the following approximations for the next root:

If $x_0$ is a solution to $f(x_0)=0$, then the next solution $x_1$ is approximately $$x_1=h_n(x_0+\pi),$$

where $h_n$ denotes $n$ applications of Newton's method. For example (sorry for the ugly $h_3$ expression),
$$h_1(x)=x-\frac{f(x)}{f'(x)}=x-\frac{x \tan (x)-1}{\tan (x)+x \sec ^2(x)}$$ and

$$h_2(x)=x-\frac{x \tan (x)-1}{\tan (x)+x \sec ^2(x)}-\frac{\left(x-\frac{x \tan (x)-1}{\tan
   (x)+x \sec ^2(x)}\right) \tan \left(x-\frac{x \tan (x)-1}{\tan (x)+x \sec
   ^2(x)}\right)-1}{\left(x-\frac{x \tan (x)-1}{\tan (x)+x \sec ^2(x)}\right) \sec
   ^2\left(x-\frac{x \tan (x)-1}{\tan (x)+x \sec ^2(x)}\right)+\tan \left(x-\frac{x
   \tan (x)-1}{\tan (x)+x \sec ^2(x)}\right)}$$
and $$h_3(x)=x+\frac{1-x \tan (x)}{x \sec ^2(x)+\tan (x)}-\frac{\frac{\left(x^2 \sec
   ^2(x)+1\right) \tan \left(\frac{2 x^2+\cos (2 x)+1}{2 x+\sin (2 x)}\right)}{x \sec
   ^2(x)+\tan (x)}-1}{\frac{\left(x^2 \sec ^2(x)+1\right) \sec ^2\left(\frac{2
   x^2+\cos (2 x)+1}{2 x+\sin (2 x)}\right)}{x \sec ^2(x)+\tan (x)}+\tan
   \left(\frac{2 x^2+\cos (2 x)+1}{2 x+\sin (2 x)}\right)}-\frac{\left(x+\frac{1-x
   \tan (x)}{x \sec ^2(x)+\tan (x)}-\frac{\frac{\left(x^2 \sec ^2(x)+1\right) \tan
   \left(\frac{2 x^2+\cos (2 x)+1}{2 x+\sin (2 x)}\right)}{x \sec ^2(x)+\tan
   (x)}-1}{\frac{\left(x^2 \sec ^2(x)+1\right) \sec ^2\left(\frac{2 x^2+\cos (2
   x)+1}{2 x+\sin (2 x)}\right)}{x \sec ^2(x)+\tan (x)}+\tan \left(\frac{2 x^2+\cos
   (2 x)+1}{2 x+\sin (2 x)}\right)}\right) \tan \left(x+\frac{1-x \tan (x)}{x \sec
   ^2(x)+\tan (x)}-\frac{\frac{\left(x^2 \sec ^2(x)+1\right) \tan \left(\frac{2
   x^2+\cos (2 x)+1}{2 x+\sin (2 x)}\right)}{x \sec ^2(x)+\tan
   (x)}-1}{\frac{\left(x^2 \sec ^2(x)+1\right) \sec ^2\left(\frac{2 x^2+\cos (2
   x)+1}{2 x+\sin (2 x)}\right)}{x \sec ^2(x)+\tan (x)}+\tan \left(\frac{2 x^2+\cos
   (2 x)+1}{2 x+\sin (2 x)}\right)}\right)-1}{\left(x+\frac{1-x \tan (x)}{x \sec
   ^2(x)+\tan (x)}-\frac{\frac{\left(x^2 \sec ^2(x)+1\right) \tan \left(\frac{2
   x^2+\cos (2 x)+1}{2 x+\sin (2 x)}\right)}{x \sec ^2(x)+\tan
   (x)}-1}{\frac{\left(x^2 \sec ^2(x)+1\right) \sec ^2\left(\frac{2 x^2+\cos (2
   x)+1}{2 x+\sin (2 x)}\right)}{x \sec ^2(x)+\tan (x)}+\tan \left(\frac{2 x^2+\cos
   (2 x)+1}{2 x+\sin (2 x)}\right)}\right) \sec ^2\left(x+\frac{1-x \tan (x)}{x \sec
   ^2(x)+\tan (x)}-\frac{\frac{\left(x^2 \sec ^2(x)+1\right) \tan \left(\frac{2
   x^2+\cos (2 x)+1}{2 x+\sin (2 x)}\right)}{x \sec ^2(x)+\tan
   (x)}-1}{\frac{\left(x^2 \sec ^2(x)+1\right) \sec ^2\left(\frac{2 x^2+\cos (2
   x)+1}{2 x+\sin (2 x)}\right)}{x \sec ^2(x)+\tan (x)}+\tan \left(\frac{2 x^2+\cos
   (2 x)+1}{2 x+\sin (2 x)}\right)}\right)+\tan \left(x+\frac{1-x \tan (x)}{x \sec
   ^2(x)+\tan (x)}-\frac{\frac{\left(x^2 \sec ^2(x)+1\right) \tan \left(\frac{2
   x^2+\cos (2 x)+1}{2 x+\sin (2 x)}\right)}{x \sec ^2(x)+\tan
   (x)}-1}{\frac{\left(x^2 \sec ^2(x)+1\right) \sec ^2\left(\frac{2 x^2+\cos (2
   x)+1}{2 x+\sin (2 x)}\right)}{x \sec ^2(x)+\tan (x)}+\tan \left(\frac{2 x^2+\cos
   (2 x)+1}{2 x+\sin (2 x)}\right)}\right)}$$

Comment: This was actually quite surprising. After 5 iterations, I had an approximation that was correct up to as many digits as my calculator. Thanks very much! Really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Although there is an accepted answer, [Lagrange reversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_reversion_theorem) gives all but the 2 smallest roots:

$$\cot(x)=x=\pi k+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left.\frac{d^{n-1}}{dw^{n-1}}\frac{\cot^{-1}(w)^n}{n!}\right|_{\pi k},k\in\Bbb Z$$

Apply [Stirling S1](https://functions.wolfram.com/IntegerFunctions/StirlingS1/23/02/0001/):

$$\left.\frac{d^{n-1}}{dw^{n-1}}\frac{\cot^{-1}(w)^n}{n!}\right|_{\pi k}=\left(\frac i2\right)^n\sum_{m=n}^\infty\frac{S_m^{(n)}(-2i)^m}{m!}\left.\frac{d^{n-1}}{dw^{n-1}}(w+i)^{-m}\right|_{\pi k}$$

Therefore:

$$\boxed{\cot(x)=x=\pi k+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{m=n}^\infty\frac{S_m^{(n)}(-m)^{(n-1)}(-2i)^{m-n}}{m!(\pi k +i)^{m+n-1}}}$$

[shown here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=cot%28x%29-x%2Cx%3D3.0pi%2Bsum%5Bsum%5B%28-2+i%29%5Em+factorialpower%28%28-m+-+n%29%2C+n+-+1%29+%283+%CF%80++%2B+i%29%5E%28-m+-+2+n+%2B+1%29+StirlingS1%28m+%2B+n%2Cn%29%2F%28%28m+%2B+n%29%21%29%2C%7Bm%2C0%2C30%7D%5D%2C%7Bn%2C1%2C30%7D%5D) and both sums are interchangeable

Comment: Sums interchangeable for $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\sum\limits_{m=0}^\infty$